# Get child nodes with the same name as parent

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I need parse all child nodes for a parent node, however the child nodes have the same name as the parent:

```xml
<div>
  <img></img>
  <div>
    <img></img>
  </div>
  <img></img>
</div>
```

I'm using Nokogiri with Ruby, but when I do `children()` from the first div node, the parsing ends prematurely at the first `div` tag.  Any workarounds to this?

Comment: Could you please show some Ruby code, or xpath selector you are using and your execution expectations.

Comment: Seems like a simple CSS (`node.css("div")`) or XPath (`node.xpath(".//div")`) selector should do the trick.

Comment: I don't understand what you want from the sample XML you've given and what you describe. There are only two kinds of nodes here—`div` and `img`—and neither make sense for your description. The `img` nodes have no children, so they are out. The top `div` does have a child `div`, but you say that the "parsing ends prematurely at the first div"…but there is only one other `div`.

Comment: I require my parser to grab all the nodes I have shown.  It ends prematurely because it starts at the top div tag, and when it hits the first closing div tag the parsing ends.  It is supposed to go all the way to the last closing div tag

Comment: @user1371011 That is still not at all clear. Nokogiri parsing the document creates a DOM with all nodes. Then you can select or traverse the nodes you need.

Answer (score 1):

I almost hate to say it but it sounds like another good case for traverse:

```
require 'nokogiri'
html = <<EOF
<div>
  <img></img>
  <div>
    <img></img>
  </div>
  <img></img>
</div>
EOF

doc = Nokogiri::HTML html
doc.root.traverse do |node|
  if node.parent.name == node.name
    puts node
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have a starting node and want all the child nodes that have the same name, here are some options for helper methods:

```ruby
# Using Ruby to Filter
def same_kind_children(node)
  node.element_children.select{ |n| n.name==node.name }
end

# Using XPath to Filter
def same_kind_children(node)
  node.xpath(node.name)
end

# Descendants instead of Children
def same_kind_descendants(node)
  node.xpath(".//#{node.name}")
end
```

If you have a particular kind of node in mind and want to find every node of that type with the same-type parent:

```ruby
divs_in_divs = doc.xpath('div/div')
```

Although it seems unlikely, if you instead don't have a particular starting node or node name in mind, but want to find all the nodes that have the same name as their parent, you could do:

```
same_kind_nested = doc.xpath('//*').select{ |node| node.name==node.parent.name }
```